# Checking if a column has a null value tsql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to determine whether a product exists in the product table already. When I run this bit of tsql, it should return 1 and exit out of the proc, because the product id 7777 does not exist in the product table, but it's returning 0. If I run it without the if statement and just execute the select statement, it says that the `@prodID` is `null`. I'm wondering why is it not going into the if statement seeing as I am checking if it's a null value. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
 Declare  @ProdID int

 select @ProdID = dbo.productTbl.ProductID
 from dbo.ProductTbl
 inner join dbo.OrderTbl
 on dbo.ProductTbl.ProductID = dbo.OrderTbl.ProductID
 where dbo.OrderTbl.ProductID = 7777


 if(@ProdID = null)
 begin 
 raiserror('The product does not exist',16,1)
 return 1
 end
 return 0
```

Comment: It does not equal null, it is null~

Comment: @Hogan This is true, but in op's defense, SQL Server isn't very consistent with that definition. You just need to look to the syntax for updating a value to `NULL`: `UPDATE TABLE SET Col = NULL`

Comment: @Lamak assignment is different to comparison.

Comment: @Hogan I know the difference, just saying that it isn't consistent.

Comment: @Lamak -- That was always my mnemonic to remember the difference

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In SQL Server, use `IS NULL` to check for a null value rather than `= null`.

```
if(@ProdID IS NULL)
begin 
raiserror('The product does not exist',16,1)
return 1
end
return 0
```

Answer (score 4):

Use IS NULL operator.
Also, there is no reason to write code after RAISERROR, it is not executed.

```
IF @ProdID IS NULL
    RAISERROR('The product does not exist',16,1)
```

Comment: `if (1 > 0)` `begin` `raiserror('x', 16, 1)` `print 1` `end` <-- this code raises the error and prints out the number

Answer (score 2):

Comparing anything to `null` results in `unkown` when using the normal compare operators like `=`, `<>`, `<=` ... which is neither `true` nor `false`. The `IS` operator can compare with `null`.

```
if(@ProdID is null)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is depends on your session settings. The `SQL-92` standard states that equality can't occur when one of operands unknown (`NULL`) and the result of equality operator is unknown in three-state logic which threats as `false` in binary logic. But you can unset the SQL Server `ANSI_NULLS` setting (**not recommend**) and use `=` operator.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
DECLARE @ProdID int
IF(@ProdID = NULL)
  PRINT 'ANSI_NULLS OFF'
```

Will print `ANSI_NULLS OFF`

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
DECLARE @ProdID int
IF(@ProdID = NULL)
  PRINT 'ANSI_NULLS OFF'
```

Nothing to print

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
DECLARE @ProdID int
IF(@ProdID IS NULL)
  PRINT 'ANSI_NULLS ON'
```

Will print `ANSI_NULLS ON`

Comment: I read that in future versions of SQL Server [ANSI_NULLS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx) will always be set on and any application setting it OFF will generate an error. So developers should avoid setting it OFF.

Comment: @Knightwisp, In post there is a phrase in bold.

Comment: I saw that. Just letting people know that the option will be done away with.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, `NULL` should be read as Unknown. Once you realize this, the following comparison table should make a lot of sense:

```
Cond1       Cond2       Cond1 AND Cond2     Cond1 OR Cond2
True        Unknown     Unknown             True
False       Unknown     Unknown             Unknown
Unknown     Unknown     Unknown             Unknown
```

If you actually want to know if it is unknown, use `IS NULL` instead of `= NULL`